# Ajax set div content

Tags: html, ajax, text, load

I call an ajax function to set my div content, the content i want to display is an inout field for my form.
I used the code below but my div still empty any suggestions please?

```
var v1='echo $this->Form->input("heure",array("label"=>false,"class"=>"form-control","default"=>"1200","options"=>'+array+'));';
jQuery('#ReservationAddForm #diiv').html('<?php  '+v1+'   ?>');
```

Comment: what's the point in using two nested id selectors?

Comment: you cannot pass PHP code via js. It won't be executed. This is not ajax.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I know that's the proble bcause when i do jQuery('#ReservationAddForm #diiv').html(v1); I got exaclty what I want so any suggestion please to deal with this problem?

Comment: @Barudar that has no negative effect

Comment: @AfafBENZINOUN I understand that, but I thought there was maybe a good reason to do that, otherwise it just complicates the code and worsen CSS maintenability, just my opinion though

Comment: @Barudar thanks for sharing your opinion btw I solved the problem by appending the attribute option for each value

Comment: @AfafBENZINOUN you're welcome